# Prove that $\int_0^2\Big(\int_{y/2}^2e^{-x^2}dx\Big)dy=1-e^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Prove that$$\int_0^2\Big(\int_{y/2}^1e^{-x^2}dx\Big)dy=1-e^{-1}$$
I'm curious how to approach that kind of problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

For the integral $\int_0^2\int_{y/2}^1e^{-x^2}\,dx\,dy$ change the order of integration to

$$\int_0^1 \left(\int_{0}^{2x}e^{-x^2}\,dy\right)\,dx$$